# unable to configure iis express for vs 2017

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, iis-express

Ever since the last windows update, I have been having problems configuring connecting to a local hostname. But my workaround was to connect to localhost:60856. Now all of a sudden, I can't connect at all with the following error:

> the following error occurred when trying to configure IIS Express for Project MantleMapperDotNet.WebCore. The Web Server 'localhost:60856' could not be found

I have scoured the internet for this but to no avail. Following are the things I've tried:

```
1. deleted .vs folder in vs project
2. deleted IISExpress folder in documents
3. re-installed iisexpress
4. running vs2017 as admin (which i always do).
5. running netsh-http to see if there's a binding already
6. restarting windows
```

can somebody please tell me what exactly is going on and how i can resolve this issue?

Comment: What IIS Express bindings are listed in your `.csproj` file?

Comment: my csproj doesn't have any iis express bindings

Comment: You didn't include much detail in the question. Run some diagnostics to reveal your project settings, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/vs-diagnostics.html